# open word file from taskpan add-in

Tags: office-js

I need to open another Word file from SharePoint document library in task path add-in. Is there anyway we can do from Office.js? I don't want copy of specific document , it should open the same remote document.

Answer (score 1):

Word Add-ins (i.e Office.js) are attached/inserted into a document so this workflow doesn't make a lot of sense. You would end up requiring the user to create a new document and attach your add-in just so they could then download a different Word file and open that in another instance of Word.

If you're looking to open files from SharePoint, you should use the Graph or SharePoint REST APIs. One of the properties exposed through these APIs is a [webUrl](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem). When followed, this URI will open the document in the correct editor for that document type (Word, Excel, etc.).